# StateMachine over multiple Entities

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, workflow, state-machine

I have 4 entity types, each has its own StateMachine. There are transitions which also should invoke transitions on one or more different entity types.

I can solve this via the event system (either in `entered` or `transition` events) but this just doesn't look right. And it's hard to follow all cases and ensure that all dependencies are taken care of.

What would be a design-pattern for such a use-case? I need a way to connect independent StateMachines together.

Comment: some code snippets would be really clarifying. Have you considered to use a [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)?

Comment: I try to give you a better example. One Entity is `Order` it has states like incoming, open, packaging, fullfilled. If the inventory for a `OrderItem` is not available, a `ProductionQueue` Item is created - this Entity also has states like waiting_on_slot, in_production, ready, done. The `Order` state is in open while the product is produced, when the product reaches state `done` the `Order` moves ahead to `packaging`. This is a oversimplified example, in the application there are 5 Entity types with a own state machine, but are influenced by other transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I appreciated @StepUp's answer, it doesnt quite fit my needs. The Applicaiton already uses events quite a bit (or read messages). CQRS would be a major rewrite and as the auditing of the state changes is not needed I dont see a big enough benefit in it.
Saga seems intresting but as this is not a microservice context is would be to much.

After thinking about it for quite some time I come to the realisation that Observer would just inverse the responsability to the other side. I need something central.

The solution will be a [Mediator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator) Pattern. The Mediator (and only the mediator) will know about which workflow has dependencies on other workflows.
The Workflow itself dont need to know this. As the StateMachine already fires events, I can use them to call the mediator and the Mediators will know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern would be really appropriate for the case where entities are in one project. Otherwise, if there are microservices, then it is possible to apply the following patterns.

It seems that you have entities that can be separated from each other and these entities can be considered as a standalone microservice. If yes, then we can try to apply the following patterns of microservices.

### Pattern: [Messaging](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/messaging.html)

Use asynchronous messaging for inter-service communication. Services communicating by exchanging messages over messaging channels.
There are several different styles of asynchronous communication:

- Request/response - a service sends a request message to a recipient and expects to receive a reply message promptly
- Notifications - a sender sends a message a recipient but does not expect a reply. Nor is one sent.
- Request/asynchronous response - a service sends a request message to a recipient and expects to receive a reply message eventually
- Publish/subscribe - a service publishes a message to zero or more recipients
- Publish/asynchronous response - a service publishes a request to one or recipients, some of whom send back a reply

### Pattern: [Saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html)

Implement each business transaction that spans multiple services as a saga. A saga is a sequence of local transactions. Each local transaction updates the database and publishes a message or event to trigger the next local transaction in the saga. If a local transaction fails because it violates a business rule then the saga executes a series of compensating transactions that undo the changes that were made by the preceding local transactions.

### Pattern: [Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS)](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html)

Define a view database, which is a read-only replica that is designed to support that query. The application keeps the replica up to data by subscribing to Domain events published by the service that own the data.